# Discord.js memberCount and members++ return different values

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently I'm developing a Discord bot function for counting users in guilds which are using my bot.
Strangely I have noticed that countMembers and iterating through guild and increasing the members counter return different values

```
client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    var cnt = 0;
    console.log(guild.name + " " +guild['memberCount'])
    guild.members.forEach((member) => {
        cnt = cnt +1;
            if(member.presence.status == 'online' || member.presence.status == 'idle' || member.presence.status == 'dnd'){
                var data = guild.name + ":@" + member.id + "\n";
                fs.appendFile('guild-audit.txt', data, function (err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                }); 
            }else{
                var data = guild.name + ":" + member.id + "\n";
                fs.appendFile('guild-audit.txt', data, function (err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                }); 
            }
    })
    console.log(guild.name + " " + cnt.toString());
})
```

For example:

> memberCount = GuildX 1596
>   cnt = GuildX 175
>   memberCount = GuildY 2385
>   cnt = GuildY 2365

Where is the difference between memberCount and iterating through the members?
I checked the documentation and in my opinion both should return the exact same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so sure but `guild.members` might only have the cached members. You can try fetch all the members and count them with something like this:

```
client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    guild.fetchMembers().then(g => {
        let count = 0;
        g.members.forEach((member) => {
            count++;
        });
        console.log(count);
    });

});
```

Comment: It looks like this might work. You are right, I was in contact with members of the official Discordjs channel and they said it only has cached members. It looks like fetching the members takes a long time and the other processes are continuing before fetching has finished. Do you think its possible to wait to write into the files before the fetching has finished?
Unfortunately I need to do it this way because I need the user/group relation.

Comment: You can make the whole function async and await for the result

Comment: I have updated my question with the async await method. Could it look something like this?

Comment: not quite. you will need to update all functions that you pass unit you reach that.